# How to Open Default browser and target an element?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi all I have done some google work and not come up with a great deal apart from using the browser within a From which I dont want to do.

Has anybody some sample code or a good resource that is detailed enough to get me on my way plesae

So for example

```
    Process.Start("https://www.google.com")
```

and target the search element with a string and click search.

Using the default browser

Please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing something like this would work:

```
string mySearchQuery = "this is a search example";
Process.Start("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(mySearchQuery));
```

If I'm understanding you correctly, this would use the default browser set in windows, then the query is just passed in as a GET request (that's the ?q variable).

Comment: Funny enough this does not enter the string and click search ;). Interesting how questions often try to suggest part of irrelevant solutions.

Comment: The way the question was phrased made it seem like OP simply wanted to execute a search query using the OS default browser, if OP really wants to automate entering text and clicking the search button, then perhaps TestStack.White may be of assistance. To me though that seems like a roundabout way of opening a browser and searching a query.

Comment: you are totally correct. I think you have misread my comment. You got my upvote.

Comment: @D.Foley Hi yes your understanding is correct and the method you have posted although I can use that its not what I really want. Using google was a bad choice for me maybe as that just search's the entire web for the string.

Comment: @D.Foley , Lets take this site: `"https://www.education.gov.au"` and then I want to target the search box with my string

Comment: @lashja okay interesting, you want to actually automate interaction with a web page. I have never done that before but the following tool claims to be able to do the task you are referring to: http://www.seleniumhq.org/